# Outputting a fraction on one line with an oblique division sign

Tags: output-formatting, text, output

How can I make *Mathematica* output a fraction as `x/2` as opposed to the `x` on top with a horizontal bar and `2` on the bottom?

Perhaps I need to work more with `Riffle` but so far I cannot get it. I have tried concatenating strings, but *Mathematica* reverses the order of the two elements.
Specifically, I am trying to put the symbol `theta` with a subscript `i` and then a division by `2`. It is going onto a figure, and is very difficult to read with the vertical division.

My code is:

```
Do[
  alabel[i] = 
   Text[StyleForm[Subscript["\[Theta]", i]/2, FontSize -> 10, 
                  FontColor -> Black, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
        {Re[ww[tt[[3]]]], Im[ww[tt[[3]]]]} + .2 {Cos[aloc3[[i]]], Sin[aloc3[[i]]]}, 
        ioffset[i]]
  , {i, 1, 6}];

th3 = Graphics[Table[alabel[j], {j, 1, 6}]];
```

(The coordinate `ww[[tt[[33]]]]` is just some point in the plane).

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish by inserting text with 3D coordinates into a 2D graphics object. Could you clarify your Question regarding that.

Answer (score 4):

```
$PrePrint = 
  RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#] //. 
     FractionBox[x_, y_] :> 
      RowBox[{If[Head[x] === RowBox, RowBox[{"(", x, ")"}], x], "/", 
        If[Head[y] === RowBox, RowBox[{"(", y, ")"}], y]}]] &;
```

Then every fraction in your output will be of the form `x/y`.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want your labels inserted into a 2D Graphic, it can be done like this:

```
With[{n = 3},
  Module[{pts, lbls},
    SeedRandom@1; pts = RandomReal[1., {n, 2}];
    lbls = 
      Table[
        Text[Row[{Subscript[θ, i], "/\[ThinSpace]2"}, "", 
          BaseStyle -> {"TR", 10}], pts[[i]]], 
        {i, Range @ n}];
    Framed @ Graphics[lbls]]]
```

[image: lbls.png]

The salient points in the above example are in the use of `Row` with the option `BaseStyle` and in adding a `\[ThinSpace]` to adjust the spacing between the slash and the denominator `2`. Without the `\[ThinSpace]` the text looks too tight.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the slash to not be written in the standard form:

```
Plot[Sin[2 Pi t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> Row[{Subscript[θ, i], "/", 2}]]
```

[image]