# How to write beveled fractions?

Tags: formatting, undocumented

How to write beveled fractions like ${}^a/_b$?

In contrast to $\frac{a}{b}$ and $a/b$ (see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33618/4678) question).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is the undocumented option `Beveled` in the `FractionBox`

```
FractionBox[a, b, Beveled -> True] // DisplayForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

One can use `Style` and `FractionBoxOptions` to set `Beveled`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  Ticks -> {Pi Range[-2, 2, 1/2], Automatic},
  BaseStyle -> {FractionBoxOptions -> {Beveled -> True}}]
```

It doesn't look too good here, though:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This looks ok,

```
Style[3 Pi/2, FractionBoxOptions -> {Beveled -> True}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but not in the `"Label"` style,

```
Style[3 Pi/2, FractionBoxOptions -> {Beveled -> True}, "Label"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example! Fractions in the "Label" style is looks ok for me (*Mathematica* 9.0.1, Linux): http://i.stack.imgur.com/nnbza.png

Comment: @ybeltukov It seems to be better on Linux than on my Mac.