# How to show the fraction line as a slash instead of horizontal bar in plot tick labels?

Tags: output-formatting

Is there any option to show the fraction numbers in the tick labels of a plot in the format of `2/3` instead of using a horizontal bar as the fraction line?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33655/how-to-write-beveled-fractions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could specify a custom label for each tick, programmatically generated using the `InputForm` of the fraction, which uses the horizontal dash. For instance:

```
Plot[
 x, {x, 0, 3},
 Ticks -> {{#, InputForm[#]} & /@ Range[0, 3, 1/3], Automatic}
]
```

[image: with axes]

---

To address your comment regarding the dropped labels, you may be better off using a `Frame` and `FrameLabels` instead:

```
Plot[
 x, {x, 0, 3},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameTicks -> {{#, InputForm[#]} & /@ Range[0, 3, 1/3], Automatic}
]
```

[image: with frame]

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that Mathematica sometimes omits some tick labels, which is also the case in your plot above. Is there a way of letting it not omit any tick labels if they are given in a list, e.g. the 0 in your list `Range[0, 3, 1/3]`?

Comment: @nanjun Yes, but perhaps a frame would be easier to use in that case; see my updated answer.

Comment: I wonder what is the criterion that Mathematica drops labels? Using frame is a way around but it shows a little bit more before 0. Is it possible to disable it from dropping labels?

Comment: @nanjun It drops that $0$ label because, when axes are present, it would be positioned at the axis intersection point, and it would be awkwardly placed. I don't know of a simple way of forcing its placement. Additionally, the amount of padding on each axis (i.e. the amount of "extra space" you were referring to) should be exactly the same whether you are using axes or frames, and is controlled by `PlotRangePadding` which for `Plot` is set as 2% by default (i.e. `Scaled[0.02]`), if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 9):

```
ClearAll[fractionToRow]
fractionToRow = RawBoxes @* 
   ReplaceAll[FractionBox -> (RowBox[{#, "/", #2}] &)] @* ToBoxes @* TraditionalForm

plt1 = Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 300, 
   Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic}];

plt2 = Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, ImageSize -> 300, 
   Ticks -> {{#, fractionToRow @ #} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic}];

Row[{plt1, plt2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

This approach works for simple inputs (as is usually the case for tick labeling).

Another example:

```
TraditionalForm[Style[Pi^(I/2)/ (I + E/Pi), 24]]
```

> [image]

```
fractionToRow @ Style[Pi^(I/2)/(I + E/Pi), 24]
```

[image]

For more complicated inputs more work may be needed for appropriate parsing.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thank you for the generous bounty.

Answer (score 8):

If one is allowed to use a package, here is another possibility. First load [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) then

```
SetOptions[MaTeX, "Preamble" -> {"\\usepackage{nicefrac}"}];
makeFrac[n_] := If[Denominator[n] == 1, MaTeX[n, Magnification -> 1.5], 
   MaTeX["\\nicefrac{" <> ToString[Numerator[n]] <> "}{" <> 
     ToString[Denominator[n]] <> "}", Magnification -> 1.5]];

texStyle = {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontSize -> 14};

Plot[x, {x, 0, 3}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, makeFrac[#]} & /@ Range[0, 3, 1/3], Automatic}, 
 BaseStyle -> texStyle]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would do both axes using Latex myself and not one to make it look better. And I think the fractions look better than using Mathematica's own typesetting ;)