# axis label format

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am plotting the following function

```
g[x_, y_] := 2 (1 + Cos[x] + Cos[y])
Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, PlotRange -> Full, 
AxesLabel -> {Subscript[k, x], Subscript[k, y], Subscript[λ, i]}, 
AxesStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 35], 
Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Specularity[White, 20], Opacity[0.9]]},
Lighting -> "Neutral", Ticks -> {{-Pi, -Pi/2, 0, Pi/2, Pi}, {-Pi, -Pi/2, 0, Pi/2, Pi},{-2, 0, 2, 4, 6}}, 
TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times", Black, FontSize -> 25], 
PlotPoints -> 100, BoxRatios -> {1., 1., .5}]
```

The output is:

[image]

How can I change the ticks $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$  to $\pm \pi/2$?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. The plot seems fine to me. Every expression in Wolfram Language has different "representations" (or forms). $\pi/2$ can be represented by its ``InputForm`` as ``Pi/2`` or by its ``FullForm`` as ``Times[Rational[1, 2], Pi]``. But these two expressions are two sides of the same coin, so to speak. What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I hope the edit clarifies what I would like to achieve

Comment: Ah, I see. The solution can be found either in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33663/75628) or [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/218884/75628).

Comment: Thanks, the answer is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136381/how-to-show-the-fraction-line-as-a-slash-instead-of-horizontal-bar-in-plot-tick/218884#218884