# Fine tuning PlotLabel graphics - Lissajous Curves

Tags: graphics, output-formatting

Overall, I'm quite happy with my **[Lissajous Curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LissajousCurve.html)** poster maker; however, getting the final touches of the graphics just right has been a challenge. I've tried two different ways of constraining equally the proportions between curves: 1) Force the plot label ratio above to one line and; 2) Tried to force the proportions of the using `PlotRange`. I don't suppose there are any *Mathematica* experts out there who would care to share some ways of improving this graphical function? (I'm hoping to do some really big plots using my free *Mathematica* online cloud credits.)

```
makeLcurves[cols_,rows_] := Module[{graphics, radius = 0.45},
 (* Subroutines *)
 functionX[anglevar_, freq_] := radius * Sin[freq anglevar];
 functionY[anglevar_, freq_] := radius * Cos[freq anglevar];
 (* Draw Graphics*)
  graphics = Table[
  ParametricPlot[{functionX[t,x],functionY[t,y]},{t,0,2 Pi },
  Frame->False,
  Axes->False,
  PlotStyle->Directive[Thick,Black],
  PlotRange->{{-.5,.5},{-.5,.5}},
  Mesh->Automatic,
  PerformanceGoal->"Speed",
  PlotLabel->TraditionalForm[x/y ],
  AspectRatio->1],
  {x,rows},{y,cols}
 ];
GraphicsGrid[graphics,
 Frame->All,
 ImageSize->800]
]

makeLcurves[6,6] // Rasterize
```

[image]

Comment: Write your labels along a single line, e.g., $3/2$.

Comment: Or use [`Beveled` as an option to a `FractionBox`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33656/38205). Or use `Pane` to enforce a height.

Comment: Also `PlotLabel -> Row[{x, "/", y}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PlotLabel -> ToString[x] <> "/" <> ToString[y],
```

[image]