# Animated Lissajous Curves Parametric Plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, code-review

I love mathematical GIFs' power to illustrate and communicate math concepts widely. I haven't had much luck with the build-in `ListAnimate` on MMA Online but exporting GIFs to the cloud shows great promise. [Building on an earlier question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189440/fine-tuning-plotlabel-graphics-lissajous-curves?noredirect=1#comment493652_189440), I'm wondering if this GIF can't be improved as well? Performance is a bit of an issue as I'd like to scale it up a bit in the future, but also to my eye it's not drawing as smoothy as I'd like. The code is below; enjoy, and I'd appreciate any feedback.

```
functionX[anglevar_, freq_] := radius * Sin[freq anglevar]
functionY[anglevar_, freq_] := radius * Cos[freq anglevar]

animatecurves[cols_, rows_] := Module[{radius=0.45,steps=22},
Table[
 GraphicsGrid[
  Partition[
   Flatten[Table[ParametricPlot[{functionX[t,x],functionY[t,y]},{t,0,n},
    Axes->False,
    Frame->False,
    PlotRange->{{-.5,.5},{-.5,.5}},
    PlotPoints->10,
    PlotStyle->Directive[{AbsoluteThickness[.5],Black}],
    Epilog->{AbsolutePointSize[6],Point[{functionX[n,x],functionY[n,y]}]}],
    {x,rows},{y,cols}]],
   cols],
  ImageSize->600],
 {n,0.1,4 Pi, 4 Pi/steps}
 ]
]

  Export[CloudObject["AnimatedLissajousCurves1.gif"],graphicslist,"GIF",AnimationRepetitions->Infinity]
```

[image]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any question in your post.

Comment: The gif is not as smooth (top right) as other animated plots on here and I'm wondering why because the code is nearly identical (`ParametricPlot`) in some cases. Just looking for some expertise in the nuances of Mathematica plotting.

Comment: an aside: you can remove `Partition[Flaten[...],..]`.

Comment: Try to increase the `PlotRange`. The jiggling is maybe caused by a `Point` leaving the plot range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get a smooth animation, I suggest setting the time step between the consecutive frames of the figure the same value as the `"DisplayDurations"` gif option. Since a human eye can distinguish about 10 frames per second, `0.1 [s]` time period between frames seems to be a reasonable choice. Additionally, you will get "real-time" animation, where the Lissajous figures draw with its actual frequency.

Just a very minor modification to kglr code:

```
dt = 0.1;

   animatecurves2[cols_, rows_] := Module[{radius = 0.45}, 
   Table[GraphicsGrid[Table[ParametricPlot[{functionX[t, x], functionY[t, y]}, {t, 0,  n},
       Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
       PlotRange -> {{-.55, .55}, {-.55, .55}}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
       PlotStyle -> Directive[{AbsoluteThickness[.5], Black}],
       MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{n}}, 
       MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[6]], {x, rows}, {y, cols}], 
       ImageSize -> 600], {n, 0.1, 4 Pi, dt}]]

glst = animatecurves2[6, 3];
Export["lsjcurves.gif", glst, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity,
      "DisplayDurations" -> dt]
```

[image]

If You are not satisfied with the "animation speed", You can always speed it up, by shortening the `"DisplayDurations"` time. For example by a factor of two:

```
Export["lsjcurves.gif", glst, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity,
          "DisplayDurations" -> dt/2]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have been playing with Your idea and found out that an interesting result can be obtained by switching frequency values ( `x` and `y` iterators) between rows and columns. As a result,  moving points in one column are synchronised horizontally, and points in a row are moving with the same vertical pattern as well. Add "zero frequency" cases and You have an animation which explains the origin and mechanics of the Lissajous Curves!

```
 dt = 0.1;

       animatecurves2[cols_, rows_] := Module[{radius = 0.45}, 
       Table[GraphicsGrid[Table[ParametricPlot[{functionX[t, y], functionY[t, x]}, {t, 0,  n},
           Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
           PlotRange -> {{-.55, .55}, {-.55, .55}}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
           PlotStyle -> Directive[{AbsoluteThickness[.5], Black}],
           MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{n}}, 
           MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[6]], {x, 0, rows}, {y, 0, cols}], 
           ImageSize -> 600], {n, 0.1, 4 Pi, dt}]]

    glst = animatecurves2[6, 3];
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `MeshFunctions` instead of `Epilog` and increasing `PlotRange` (per Henrik's suggestion) and `steps`:

```
animatecurves2[cols_, rows_] := Module[{radius = 0.45, steps = 44}, 
  Table[GraphicsGrid[Table[ParametricPlot[{functionX[t, x], functionY[t, y]}, {t, 0,  n},
      Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
      PlotRange -> {{-.55, .55}, {-.55, .55}}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[{AbsoluteThickness[.5], Black}],
      MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{n}}, 
      MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[6]], {x, rows}, {y, cols}], 
    ImageSize -> 600], {n, 0.1, 4 Pi, 4 Pi/steps}]]

glst = animatecurves2[6, 3];
Export["lsjcurves.gif", glst, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity,
  "DisplayDurations" -> ConstantArray[.2, Length@glst]]
```

[image]