# Is there an option to set fractional tick lables in linear form?

Tags: output-formatting

I want to set the fractional tick lables in linear form like this:
[image]

And it can be done by use Row in each label, but it's boring.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]},
 Ticks -> 
    {{
     {-2\[Pi],-2\[Pi]}, 
     {-((3 \[Pi])/2),Row[{-3 \[Pi], "/", 2}]}, 
     {-\[Pi], -\[Pi]}, 
     {-(\[Pi]/2),Row[{-\[Pi], "/", 2}]},
     {0, 0}, 
     {\[Pi]/2,Row[{\[Pi], "/", 2}]},
     {\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
     {(3 \[Pi])/2,Row[{3 \[Pi], "/", 2}]}, 
     {2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}
     },
     Automatic}
]
```

In this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33655/how-to-write-beveled-fractions) Michael E2's answer, One can use Style and FractionBoxOptions to set Beveled.

Is there a similar option to set linear fractional tick labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to define a new *Form wrapper that behaves the way you want. Unfortunately, the approach I'm going to suggest is both undocumented, and not fully functional, yet it will work for your example. So, define a new wrapper `piForm`:

```
AppendTo[$BoxForms, piForm];
ParentForm[piForm] ^= TraditionalForm;
```

`piForm[expr]` will format the expression in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), unless special [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) rules for fooForm are defined. Let's define a format rule for your ticks:

```
piForm /: MakeBoxes[Rational[a_, b_] Pi, piForm] := RowBox[{
    ToBoxes[a Pi], "/", MakeBoxes[b]
}]
```

Now, let's use `piForm` instead of [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) in your plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
    Ticks -> {Range[-2Pi, 2Pi, Pi/2], Automatic}, 
    FormatType -> piForm
]
```

[image]

An example of the deficiency of this approach:

```
Pi/2 //piForm
f[Pi/2] //piForm
```

[image]