# Better way to plot multiple discrete PDFs?

Tags: plotting, histograms, distributions

I often find myself trying to plot multiple PDFs for my courses.  I find the default tools available to me are lacking and/or cumbersome.  After readings some suggestions here, I have come up with the following code to plot 3 instances of the Binomial Distribution.  I'm  hoping this will prove useful to others (perhaps even myself).  I'm also wondering if folks can improve on this.

```
n = 12;
plist = {1/6, 1/3, 2/3};
colorList = {Magenta, Blue, Green};
Plot[Evaluate[
  Map[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, #], Floor[k]] &, 
   plist]], {k, -0.001, n + 0.001},
 Exclusions -> None,
 PlotStyle -> Map[{Thick, #} &, colorList],
 PlotLegends -> plist,
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameTicks -> {Table[i, {i, 0 , n, 2}], Automatic},
 FrameLabel -> {"Successes k", "Probability"}]
```

Here's the output
[image: plot of multiple histograms]

Comment: For example, can you comment on what you don't like about your solution?

Comment: In my opinion there is a problem with this plot, in that the steps occur at integer values on the k axis. e.g. the value of the magenta curve at k=1 is both 0.12 and 0.27. Unless you know the code that was used to create the plot, there is no way to tell which is the correct value.

Comment: Seen `DiscretePlot` ?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I tried using DiscretePlot, but I couldn't figure out an elegant way to get the lines the way I wanted instead of simple markers as is the default.

Comment: I agree with @SimonWoods that the location of the bin boundaries are ambiguous.  It seems like this could be solved by replacing "k" in "Floor[k]" with "Floor[k+1/2]" and changing the lower bound of the range of k from "-0.001" to "-0.5001"

Comment: @bobthechemist I expect there are more elegant and simpler solutions out there.  Ones where I don't have to worry about offsetting functions and such.  On a largely unrelated point, I wish the numbers in the legend were typeset as "1/6" not $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: For fraction see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33618/) question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my quick and dirty take on it using `DiscretePlot`.  (As also suggested by Sjoerd in the comments above.)  Playing around with `ExtentSize` and `ExtentMarkers` can give you a variety of choices for how the lines are displayed.

I'm not sure what constitutes "better" from your perspective, but the following code generates something similar to your solution:

```
DiscretePlot[
  {PDF[BinomialDistribution[12, 1/6], x], 
   PDF[BinomialDistribution[12, 1/3], x], 
   PDF[BinomialDistribution[12, 2/3], x]}, {x, 0, 12}, 
   ExtentSize -> Right,                            (* Lines extend to the right *)
   ExtentMarkers -> {Point, Null},                 (* Markers to resolve the ambiguity *)
   Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.25, 13.25}, {-0.01, 0.32}},   (* Set "handraulically", could be automated *)
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12}, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Number of successes (k)", 16], 
      Style["Probability", 16]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], AbsolutePointSize[6]], 
   ImageSize -> 625
]
```

The plot, in all its "glory":

[image]

Note that I have not included a legend for the plot as you have.  In my production work (final figures for journal articles or internal tech reports), I tend to do plot legends or other labelling either via `Epilog` and direct graphics commands, or by post-editing in Adobe Illustrator, depending on the complexity of the desired annotations/markup.  Not necessarily the most optimal workflow, but it gives me the greatest fine-grained control over the output.